# SonarLint connected mode is not working in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, sonarqube, typescript2.0, sonarlint, static-code-analysis

I have Sonar Lint version as 1.15.0 and Vs Code version as 1.43.I have given the server setting as

"sonarlint.connectedMode.connections.sonarqube": [
        {
            "serverUrl":"xx",//Server url
            "token": "xx"//Token generated from SonarQube
        }
    ],

This configuration is given in the user setting of Vscode.
In the work space setting.json have given the following code,

sonarlint.connectedMode.project": {
        "connectionId": "mySonar",
        "projectKey": "my-dream-app"
    }

The problem is Sonar Lint is not getting connected with the Sonarqube server.Could any one help me out why this configuration is not working .